# Meteor.publish on server doesn't show new documents on client

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe, mongo-collection

The problem is the next code on server:

```
Meteor.publish(null , function() {
    let events = [];
    Groups.find({participants: this.userId}).forEach(function(item) {
        events.push(item.latestEvent);
    });
    return Events.find({_id: {$in: events}});
});
```

doesn't provide possibility to see new documents on the client `> Events.find().fetch()`
without reloading the page.

Both collection are in the `lib` folder:

```
Groups = new Mongo.Collection('groups');
Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is in reactive source of data, but still cannot fix it.

Thank You for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right: only Events collection is reactive. There is simple way to solve it by using [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package:

```
Meteor.publishComposite(null, {
    find(){
      return Groups.find({participants: this.userId});
    },
    children: [{
      find(group){
         return Events.find({_id: {$in: group.latestEvent}});
      }
    }]
});
```

But this solution has one disadvantage: Groups documents are published as well. So, probably you should exclude some fields from it.